# rsync from one source to multiple different target directories according to pattern?

Tags: unix, backup, rsync

Assume e.g. you want to backup all files matching pattern *a* to directory *A* and all files matching pattern *b* to directory *B*. The natural way to do this are two separate `rsync` commands.

```
rsync --include="...pattern_a..." --exclude="..." user@server:sourcedir/ a/
rsync --include="...pattern_b..." --exclude="..." user@server:sourcedir/ b/
```

So far, so good. Now assume that the source dir contains lots (!) of files. Running `rsync` two times consumes a lot of resources for building the index alone.

Is there a possibility to accomplish things like that in a single `rsync` run, hence building the index just once?

Answer (score 0):

Create temporary folders on the same file-system, hard-link the files you want into each, then run rsync on each folder.

e.g.

> cp -Rl <...glob_pattern_a...> /tmp/tmp_a cp -Rl <...glob_pattern_b...>
>   /tmp/tmp_b
>
> rsync --remove-source-files /tmp/a user@server:destdir_a
>   rsync --remove-source-files /tmp/b user@server:destdir_b

If you want to do this from the dest system, you could put the 'cp' commands in a script on the source sytem.